# After opening process start command prompt how to write ipconfig in c#

Tags: c#, console-application

I am opening the command prompt from c#

```
 Process.Start("cmd");
```

when it opens i need to write ipconfig automatically such that process opens and finds the ip of the workstation, How should i do that?

Comment: If you need to find the IP Addresses of the local machine, there are better ways to do that than launching ipconfig.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "ipconfig.exe";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
return output;
```

or

EDIT

```
  Process pr = new Process();
  pr.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
  pr.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k ipconfig"; 
  pr.Start();
```

Check : [How to Execute a Command in C# ?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25983/How-to-Execute-a-Command-in-C)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); 
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
 startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
 startInfo.Arguments = "ipconfig";
 process.StartInfo = startInfo;
 process.Start();
```

or

Comment: this is not working, just the command promt is opening but its not writing ipconfig. i am nt hiding window.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 string strCmdText; 
 strCmdText= "ipconfig";
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", "/K ipconfig");
```

This `/K` parameter will start cmd with an `ipconfig` command and will show it's output on the console too.
To know more parameters which could be passed to a cmd [Go here](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

Comment: Hi, how can I send multiple parameter, example `/K ipconfig` and `Pause`

Comment: @Mowgli try `/K ipconfig & Pause`, you can use `&` for combining commands. Read the provided link for more info.

Answer (score 1):

there are specific ways to redirect standard input, standard output and error messages when running an external process like in your case, for example check here: [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx)

then plenty of examples also here on SO: [Sending input/getting output from a console application (C#/WinForms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765493/sending-input-getting-output-from-a-console-application-c-winforms)